# How to properly use scalac -Xlint

Tags: scala, compiler-flags, scalac, scala-compiler

scalax -Xlint help provides the following info:

```
$ scalac -Xlint:help
Enable or disable specific warnings
  adapted-args               Warn if an argument list is modified to match the receiver.
  nullary-unit               Warn when nullary methods return Unit.
  inaccessible               Warn about inaccessible types in method signatures.
  nullary-override           Warn when non-nullary `def f()' overrides nullary `def f'.
  infer-any                  Warn when a type argument is inferred to be `Any`.
  missing-interpolator       A string literal appears to be missing an interpolator id.
  doc-detached               A Scaladoc comment appears to be detached from its element.
  private-shadow             A private field (or class parameter) shadows a superclass field.
  type-parameter-shadow      A local type parameter shadows a type already in scope.
  poly-implicit-overload     Parameterized overloaded implicit methods are not visible as view bounds.
  option-implicit            Option.apply used implicit view.
  delayedinit-select         Selecting member of DelayedInit.
  by-name-right-associative  By-name parameter of right associative operator.
  package-object-classes     Class or object defined in package object.
  unsound-match              Pattern match may not be typesafe.
  stars-align                Pattern sequence wildcard must align with sequence component.
```

Is there a way to enable all checks? What's the semantic of `scalac -Xlint` ? will it enable all? A default set (which) ? Won't do anything?

> Note: Scala 2.11.8 and sbt 0.13.9
>
> If newer versions provide different behaviour/features let me know, as updating them is not a problem

Comment: Yes, `-Xlint` enables them all. You can check it yourself with `scala -e` and see the warning messages, for example: `scala -Xlint -e 'print("foo${1}")'`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`-Xlint` [currently means](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.12.0-M4/src/compiler/scala/tools/nsc/settings/Warnings.scala#L102) `-Xlint:_`, but that needs [to be made explicit](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-9832).

Historically, there have always been warnings that are too noisy or unreliable to enable by default, so there have always been warnings excluded from `-Xlint`.

Currently, there's [one such lintable](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.12.0-M4/src/compiler/scala/tools/nsc/settings/Warnings.scala#L30), but it's not hooked up to the command line option.

There used to be a `-Ywarn-all` that meant `-Xlint` plus those other warnings. It's not obvious why that option went away.

At one point, `-Xlint:_` was going to mean `-Ywarn-all`, with `-Xlint` to mean a recommended subset, but it turns out that people like to disable one or two lint rules with `-Xlint:-annoying,_`, which is harder to do if that enables arbitrarily many other noisy lint rules.

Normally, `scalac -X` shows defaults; but probably `scalac -Xlint:help` will be improved to show its default behavior. That default is nontrivial for something like `-Yopt`.

```
$ scalac -help
Usage: scalac <options> <source files>
where possible standard options include:
  -X                              Print a synopsis of advanced options.


$ scalac -X
Usage: scalac <options> <source files>

-- Notes on option parsing --
Boolean settings are always false unless set.
Where multiple values are accepted, they should be comma-separated.
  example: -Xplugin:option1,option2
<phases> means one or a comma-separated list of:
  (partial) phase names, phase ids, phase id ranges, or the string "all".
  example: -Xprint:all prints all phases.
  example: -Xprint:expl,24-26 prints phases explicitouter, closelim, dce, jvm.
  example: -Xprint:-4 prints only the phases up to typer.

Possible advanced options include:
  -Xlint:<_,warning,-warning>    Enable or disable specific warnings: `_' for all, `-Xlint:help' to list
```

Comment: Could '-Xdev' replace '-Ywarn-all' and friends? I'm trying to enable *all* warnings and linters so that we can generate output to be ingested into reports for the Jenkins "Warnings Next Generation" plugin.

Comment: @JesseAdelman people make jokes about how terrible warn-all is. They say they wouldn't wish it on their worst enemy, but I bet if the compiler could detect their worst enemy, they'd say OK then go ahead and enable all the nagging.

Comment: Where can I find documentation for 2.11 `scalac`?

Comment: @BradSolomon you can download a previous binary distro, and inside is `doc/tools/scalac.html` https://www.scala-lang.org/download/2.11.12.html  I don't think that is kept online; also I don't think it is updated recently.